# Ссылка на протокол через "//"

Tags: php, .htaccess, apache, http, https

Вижу на некоторых сайтах, которые используют протокол https, ссылку на их сайты не

```
https://site.ru..#не такие ссылки
//site.ru. #а вот такие
```

И я так понимаю апач или другая система, сама определяет и перекидывает на нужный протокол.

Вопрос.

Эту "проверку" протокола нужно самому писать, или апач(в моём случае) сам определит, если я буду к себе перекидывать через адресс:

```
//site.ru
```

Comment: Никто ничего не перекидывает. Если в ссылке не задан сайт - то ссылка ведет на текущий сайт. Аналогично, если не задан протокол - ссылка ведет на сайт с текущим протоколом (по которому открыта страница на которой данная ссылка)

Answer (score 3):

Не Apache Server добавляет протокол, а браузер. На сервер запрос приходит уже с протоколом. На стороне сервера нужно настроить обработку нужных протоколов и все.

Answer (score 3):

Это сугубо фронтендовая вещь, apache (или любой другой веб-сервер тут не при чём). Такая ссылка, без схемы, говорит браузеру что нужно использовать тот-же протокол который он использовал для доступа к странице на которой эта ссылка расположена.

Пример:

На сайте `example.org` eсть страница `some_page.html`, в ней есть ссылка `<a href='//example.com/another_page.html'>click me</a>` (обращаю внимание: другой домен).

Если обратиться к странице по адресу `http://example.org/some_page.html` то клик по ссылке отправит запрос по `http` (`http://example.com/another_page.html`).

Если обратиться к странице по адресу `https://example.org/some_page.html` то клик по ссылке отправит запрос по `https` (`https://example.com/another_page.html`).

Справедливо не только для `<a href>`, но и для любых других мест где используется `url` (загрузка изображений, стилей, скриптов etc). Возможно есть редкие исключения, не помню, стоит уточнить.

Смысл такой: незачем загружать дополнительные ресурсы (стили, скрипты, изображения) по `https` еслиосновная страница всё-равно загружается по `http` и её содержимое как угодно может модифицировать "человек посередине". С другой стороны не разумно (а зачастую просто невозможно) загружать ресурсы по `http` на страницу загруженную по `https`.